# Angular2 2-way databinding between parent component and directive

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

**See update below**

Still playing with Angular2 Beta, I'm trying to implement a scenario where an "editor" component template contains a directive wrapping the Ace editor. Thus, the "editor" component is the parent of the Ace wrapper directive, and I want to get the code from the directive or set the code into it.

While the directive alone works fine, when I include it in this component I get nothing displayed; yet no errors are shown in the browser's console. You can find a **repro** at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kzclJLIX6hRMWa14A0Pb.

In my implementation, the `ace.directive` directive wrapping the Ace editor  has a `text` property and a `textChanged` event.

```
import {Component,Directive,EventEmitter,ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
declare var ace: any;

@Directive({
    selector: "ace-editor",
    inputs: [
        "text"
    ],
    outputs: [
        "textChanged"
    ]
})
export class AceDirective { 
    private editor : any;
    private settingText : boolean;
    public textChanged: EventEmitter<string>;

    set text(s: string) {
        let sOld = this.editor.getValue();
        if (sOld === s) return;

        this.settingText = true;
        this.editor.setValue(s);
        this.editor.clearSelection();
        this.editor.focus();
        this.settingText = false;
    }

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        var dir = this;
        this.textChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

        let el = elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.editor = ace.edit(el);

        this.editor.on("change", (e) => {
            if (dir.settingText) return;
            dir.textChanged.next(dir.editor.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

The `editor.component` component uses the directive: it has an `xml` property representing the XML code being edited. Its template contains the directive as follows:

```
<ace-editor id="editor" [text]="xml" (textChanged)="onXmlChanged()"></ace-editor>
```

i.e. the directive's `text` property is bound to the parent component's `xml`
property, and the directive's `textChanged` event is handled by the parent's
`onXmlChanged` function.

This being a 2-way databinding, AFAIK I could also try:

```
<ace-editor id="editor" [(ngModel)]="xml"></ace-editor>
```

Here is the editor's code:

```
import {Component,EventEmitter} from "angular2/core";
import {AceDirective} from "./ace.directive";

@Component({
    selector: "mit-editor",
    directives: [AceDirective],
    template: `<div>
      <ace-editor id="editor" [text]="xml" (textChanged)="onXmlChanged()"></ace-editor>
    </div>
    `,
    inputs: [
        "xml"
    ]
})
export class EditorComponent { 
    public xml: string;

    constructor() {
        this.xml = "";
    }

    public onXmlChanged(xml: string) {
        this.xml = xml;
    }
}
```

**Update #1**
For some reason, the Plunker does not transpile and load my .ts files other than the preexisting ones, so I continued troubleshooting locally.

As for the question, I found I have to add the `$event` argument to the call in the template (see my comment). My directive is now:

```
import {Component,Directive,EventEmitter,ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
declare var ace: any;

@Directive({
    selector: "ace-editor",
    inputs: [
        "text"
    ],
    outputs: [
        "textChanged"
    ]
})
export class AceDirective { 
    private editor : any;
    public textChanged: EventEmitter<string>;

    set text(s: string) {
        if (s === undefined) return;
        let sOld = this.editor.getValue();
        if (sOld === s) return;

        this.editor.setValue(s);
        this.editor.clearSelection();
        this.editor.focus();
    }

    get text() {
        return this.editor.getValue();
    }

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        var dir = this;
        this.textChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

        let el = elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.editor = ace.edit(el);
        let session = this.editor.getSession();
        session.setMode("ace/mode/xml");
        session.setUseWrapMode(true);

        this.editor.on("change", (e) => {
            let s = dir.editor.getValue();
            dir.textChanged.next(s);
        });
    }
}
```

The editor component template contains the directive like this:

```
<ace-editor id="editor" [text]="xml" (textChanged)="onXmlChanged($event)"></ace-editor>
```

Anyway, note that if I now try to programmatically set the editor's component `xml` property, Angular starts and endless loop as the change triggers the event on the ace editor which emits the event which sets the `xml` property again, and so forth. Probably it's just me doing something wrong, but currently I had to use this hack in the code, and of course I don't like it:):

```
// ...
export class EditorComponent { 
    private _xml: string;
    private _changeFrozenCount: number;

    public set xml(s: string) {
        this._xml = s; 
    }
    public get xml() : string {
        return this._xml;
    }

    constructor(private editorService: EditorService, private xmlService: XmlService) {
        this._xml = "";
    }

    public onXmlChanged(xml: string) {
        if (this._changeFrozenCount > 0) {
            this._changeFrozenCount--;
            return;
        }
        this._xml = xml;
    }

    public changeXml() {
        this._changeFrozenCount = 1;
        this._xml = "<sample>Hello</sample>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Naftis. I tried to use your plunk but I can't fill the ace area. Is it something normal?

Comment: Hi, thanks, no it's not normal. It's part of the issue, but I cannot see any error message logged from the console. I tried a number of changes in a local copy, and found that at least for data binding I can solve by adding the $event parameter to the call, e.g.[text]="xml" (textChanged)="onXmlChanged($event). Not sure about why Plunker is not even showing the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
directives: [EditorComponent]
```

in your app.ts file. Currently the `directives` array is empty (`[]`) in your plunker. Just make this change and it works, and if you set `onXmlChanged($event)` it won't even error out when you type inside the editor :)

Comment: Thanks you're right, I had forgotten to add the import in the app.ts! As for $event, I had just found this. I updated the post before I could read this, yet the "endless update" issue remains.